# disabled bootstrap button can be accessed from tabbing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, disabled-control

So by doing the below the button is supposed to be disabled, but you can actually access the button using tabbing:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary disabled">Submit</button>
```

So to prevent that from happening do I have to add `tabindex="-1"` to all of the elements I want to be disabled? I thought by using the disabled class this will be taken care of, but it seems not.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Have you confirmed if this behavior occurs when you also apply the `disabled` attribute to `<button>` ?

Comment: @Robert yes, the same, that's why I'm asking the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is annoying but also rather logical. Tabbing and focus is a different browser-task; CSS is (with a few exceptions) mostly about visual behaviour. Adding `tabindex="-1"` would become hellish, since you most likely also want to get the button focused through tabbing once it is no longer disabled.

I would suggest a handler that moves focus to either the previous or next element, if the button is receiving focus and it is `disabled` :

```js
$('button').focus(function(e) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
    e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.focus()
    //or e.currentTarget.previousElementSibling.focus()
  }
})
```